# android studio,all text and buttons in top corner. how do i fix this?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewGuessGame"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:text="Guess Game"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="6dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewGameRules"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="61dp"
    android:text="Game rules: guess the wrong number and you loose a point. Guess the right number and get one point "
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.13"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="54dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewResult"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:text="Points : 0 "
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="233dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.455" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonL"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="0"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="37dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="146dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonR"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="0"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="208dp"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/buttonL" />
```

I want to make it so the two buttons go  next to each other and text view game rules under the textviewguessgame. I am trying to make it so they do not go in the left corner all staked up together. Is there a video i could look at too so i don't have to keep asking questions each time?

Comment: What is your layout? See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22160842/what-is-the-android-equivalent-of-this-xaml-grid) SO question.

Answer (score 0):

Everything depends on the layout you are using. Looks like you are using ConstraintLayout but you didn't copy all the xml code. I recommand RelativeLayout, things aren't complicated in RelativeLayout and it is used to make layouts for different screen sizes.

Here's android developers official page tutorial for RelativeLayout.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html

Sometimes you want to use another layout but in your case RelativeLayout will be just fine.

Comment: yeah, thanks for the info. I am just wondering how is this a bad question?

Comment: I didn't down vote because I used to have troubles with layouts in android, though it is a bad question, watch some tutorials about android layouts in xml, there's plenty on youtube. It is only hard at the beginning. Good luck!

Comment: thanks, i hope so  coding has been a dream since i was a kid.

Comment: Keep it up ! I took this course on udemy and it helped, it's free if you're interested https://www.udemy.com/become-an-android-developer-from-scratch/

Answer (score 0):

According to your layout specifications, I think linear layout with vertical orientation is the best deal.Try below code.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewGuessGame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Guess Game"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewGameRules"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="61dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Game rules: guess the wrong number and you loose a point. Guess the right number and get one point " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewResult"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Points : 0 "/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonL"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonR"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thanks! Sorry if that was  a stupid question and thanks for replying.